# Redirect host ip to load balancer in apache tomcat cluster

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp, catalina

I have a load balancing cluster set up with Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 7 nodes. I know clients wouldn't normally know the IP of the nodes, but I'm curious if there is a way to configure the nodes to redirect requests to the load balancer.  Part of this already works, for example the url:

```
Request 1) https://<node-ip>/webapp
```

results in:

```
https://<lb-ip>/webapp
```

This is good.

But I get a 403 response if I specify any other url, such as:

```
Request 2) https://<node-ip>/webapp/  <-- note the extra slash
```

Is there a way to make Request 2 redirect to the load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you access the URL of your load balancer, insted of your nodes? The LB is then redirecting to your nodes and back. An AJP mapping normally looks like this:

```
JkMount /YouApp       balancer
JkMount /YouApp/*     balancer
```

Comment: I'm in agreement that the URL of the load balancer should be used.  But my question is can I configure what the nodes do if they are accessed directly (for whatever reason).  The fact that there is a partial solution is tantalizing.

Comment: To avoid them being accessed directly you can turn off the Coyote web server in Tomcat. Just comment out the connector using protocol="HTTP/1.1" in server.xml.